# Chrome Inspector : Shortcut for - *right click > Copy > Copy Selector*

Tags: html, google-chrome, shortcut, inspector

I'm doing repeated tasks of inspecting an element >

> `right click > copy > smudge a little > copy selector`
>
> > paste.

Is there any way I can shorten the `~` part ?

I have to keep doing this for 10+ blocks 100+ times... Help